# Live console output in Sublime Text 2

Tags: build, sublimetext2, moai

I managed to create a simple build configuration for my project that builds and also launches it. However the console freezes during the execution and it only prints the messages generated by the application after I close it. 
The build configuration looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["${project_path:${folder}}/run.bat"]
}
```

The run.but just runs the application like this:

```
"%MOAI_BIN%\moai" "config\config.lua" "main.lua"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue when running the Moai host from Sublime Text 2 on Mac OS X and was able to fix it by calling

```
io.stdout:setvbuf("no")
```

at the beginning of my Lua code, thanks to [this snippet](http://www.moaisnippets.info/moai-stdout-is-not-immediately-visible).